# ruby and nested loops

Tags: erb, puppet

Hi I'd like some help on how to code this in erb in puppet, basically I have

```
server::actionhost { 'details':
    servername[ 'felix', 'washington', ],
    ipa [ '192.168.43.5', '192.168.43.11', ],
    enviro [ 'prod', 'uat', ],
}
```

I now want to print this out to a file with each respective element from each array in one line, i.e the output from the template file in my class should be like:

```
felix 192.168.43.5 prod
washington 192.168.43.11 uat
```

When I attempted this I wrote the following code in my template file:

```
<% servername.each do |name| -%>
<% ipa.each do |ip| -%>
<% enviro.each do |env| -%>
<%= name %> <%= ip %> <%= env %>
<% end -%>
<% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

but what I get is recursive prints of netmask and ipa instead of a print from each array and then move to the next array element.

Would appreciate some guidance on how to accomplish the correct output?

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 2):

How  about trying something like dictionary. A similar approach worked for me hope it is  helpful to you. My problem was, I had different variables and each should have a different value or parameters.

Define the variable like

```
 $file_threshold = {
          'received' => '10',
          'doneJobs' => '20',
          'recvq'    => '30',
          'sendq'    => '40',
          'doneq'    => '50',
          'docq'     => '60',}
```

In the template file

```
<%  @file_threshold.each do |key,value| -%>

cmd = check_file.sh <%=  key %>  <%= value%>

<% end -%>
```

Out:

```
....
cmd = check_file.sh doneq 50
....
```

Answer (score 1):

One can execute Ruby code (the following is Ruby code) inside an .erb, if need be.  The main things in this case are:  defining a multi-dimensional array and using Ruby's transpose method for arrays.

```
<% details = [servername, ipa, env]; transposed = details.transpose; transposed.each {|x| print x.at(0), " ", x.at(1), " ", x.at(2), "\n"}  %>
```

Comment: I'd just use: `<%= [servername, ipa, env].transpose.map {|x| "%s %s %s" % x }.join("\n") %>`

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of dicey because it assumes that you are absolutely sure that your arrays line up, but:

...<% servername.each_with_index do |name, i| -%>
.....<%= name %> <%= ipa[i] %> <%= enviro[i] %>
...<% end %>

(please ignore the ... i couldn't get the template code to appear correctly otherwise!)